# Is it possible to load knitr chunks from a URL

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr

I am attempting to pull R code chunks over HTTPS from an R script into a LaTeX document.
The .R file is in rstudio server and shared via webdav.
The LaTeX document resides on a server that cannot store files locally (ShareLaTeX). 
Therefore, to get around the problem, I thought I'd use URL calls,

the following works for pulling in data:

```
<<load_data, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=

library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://user:pass@my.webdav.server.net/webdav/data/data.csv")
y <- read.csv(text = x,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings = "NA")
y

@
```

However, I would also like to pull in code chunks.
I have tried the following:

```
<<external-code, cache=FALSE>>=

z<-getURL("https://user:pass@my.webdav.server.net/webdav/model.R")

read_chunk(z, lines = code, labels = "foo")

@
```

However, this returns the error:

```
error in read_chunk(z, lines = code, labels = "foo"): object `code` not found
```

Is there some way to make knitr parse this variable as a file, or read the external URL?

Comment: What's `code`? That error has nothing in particular to do with knitr.

Comment: I think 'code' is the internal variable for the function read_chunk()

Comment: Ok, I removed, the lines=code from the above and now get the error: Error in file(con, "r"): cannot open the connection.  It does seem to be reading the file correctly, however, as it also dumps the text of the file.